# Reading and writing on a text file Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

My objective is to save "textbox" input to a text file and then being able to load that saved  text from the same text file back to a textbox.

I think that one of my mistakes is reading on Console.

```
namespace aaa
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "test.txt";

            FileStream fs = null;

            fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);

            writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            public static void Main() 
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt")) 
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Windows.Storage.StorageFile in both Windows Phone Runtime and Windows Phone Silverlight apps.

There are examples in the MSDN documentation in the [Working with data and files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br229562.aspx) section. In particular see [Quickstart: Local app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx) or [Quickstart: Roaming app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx) and [Quickstart: Reading and writing files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx)

This last Quickstart has demos directly on reading and writing short text snippets to a file:

```
// Create sample file; replace if exists.
StorageFolder folder =
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile =
    await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, textBox1.text);
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! There are so many overcomplex or not working examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

in windows phone you don't have such a direct access to the file system.

you can use the isolated file storage to read and write files.

here you find a broad overview of the features:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile

(Caution: This is for windows phone 7, for windows phone 8.1 see the other answer)

Comment: You can also have access to *KnownFolders* and whole SD card, where you can surely read/write files.

Comment: For new code use the modern StorageFile API rather than isolated storage. You'll get access to new features such as roaming and be better set up for the future. The only reason to use isolated storage in a WP8.1 app is if you're bringing forward code that already used it for WP7.

Comment: sry for citing the old API, the windows phone api is changing very fast, the camera api is changing I think for the third time :( ...